# unexpected return value of time command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time

These commands work fine: (calculates time between opening and closing the program)

```
time gedit
time emacs
time vim
```

But this command always gives a time under 1 second. It's probably time which opening the program took.

```
time gvim
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI version of vim will detach from the foreground terminal by default - you can tell it not to - and so has "exited" from the point of view of the time command.

Detaching means it doesn't block the terminal which, for a GUI application, is a pretty reasonable choice.

Your analysis - that this is roughly the startup time - is on the money.

Comment: What else can I do to evaluate the time for gvim, else than *tell it not to detach*

Comment: There isn't a convenient way to get time(1) to do that other than keep gvim in the foreground, which might be what you want anyhow.  You could monitor the process table and track the life of the forked gvim that way, you could use strace and follow forks, and get time that way, or you could do something with cgroups to follow it.  Just asking it to stay in the foreground instead is probably the right choice though - `time gvim -f ...`